# Xml file comparison

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, spfx

Good afternoon All,

I want to compare XML file stored in SharePoint Online with its previous version and show the difference between them.

Could you please suggest any feature in SharePoint Online or custom solution to achieve it?

Thank you very much for your support.

Regards,
Maple Leaf

Comment: What  are you using to customize front-end? React? Angular? Vanila js? Do you use SPFx or SharePoint Add-ins?

Comment: Thank you Denis for your prompt response. I am new to SharePoint Online and exploring the platform for possible solution of the requirements.  There are two aspects of it, Firstly, I want to display XML using XSLT in SharePoint Online. Other is compare the previous version of XML file with current version and show the differences as an HTML page. I am looking for any simplest solution for XML comparison either using SharePoint Add-ins or SPFx development. Any suggestions for solution is appreciated. Please note: I am beginner to the Sharepoint online & SPFx environment. Thank you very much. ML

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SharePoint Online does not have such feature for file content comparison.

I believe there are other tools capable of this task, for example, open-source tool [**NotePad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with **Compare** Plugin, or the very old [**XMLDiffPatch**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XMLDiffPatch/) tool from Microsoft.

Reference that might be helpful: [Programmatic XML Diff / Merge in C#.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341490/programmatic-xml-diff-merge-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you very much Chelsea for the nice idea.Actually, I want to show the difference between two XML files or between two different version of same XML file in an HTML format. The reason is that it would be user-friendly for the end user to see the differences in the SharePoint Environment rather than installing software on their systems. Any ideas or pointers is appreciated? Thank you again for your support.

Comment: @user95345 Your concern is understood. However, SharePoint itself does not provide such function with a built-in solution. I believe you can either submit this idea via SharePoint UserVoice forum, or seek help from third-party tools.